Backspace key is not working in Visual Studio Code
When I want to delete a code in Visual Studio Code, the delete key works but the backspace key does not work
Nothing appears in the shortcut section changed by the user, but backspace does not work

Welcome! What do you see when you troubleshoot your keybindings? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. Include also the top section of the file opened by running Developer: Inspect Key Mappings in the command palette and all following text that is related to the keys of interest.

Check the Keybindings.

Open Keyboard Shortcut
Press Ctrl + K Ctrl + S or go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.
Search for Backspace - In the search bar (at the top) type Backspace.
Reset Keybindings - Click on the three-dot menu at the top-right of the Keyboard Shortcuts pane and select Reset Keybinding.

If it does not work, try reinstalling the Visual Studio Code.

Unfortunately, even though I click on the three dots on the shortcut menu, there is no option to reset shortcuts.
